# Bacterial infectious diseases dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, releasing-data, metadata

Does anyone know of a dataset relating:

- bacteria (not viruses or fungi)
- infectiousness
- symptoms

...or something of the sort?
I'm looking to classify infectiousness (ie. infectious/not infectious) via bacterial genomic sequencing/metadata. I have the capability to match names to genome fragments from other sets.

Comment: Post has been updated

Comment: This is not a binary distinction. Many bacteria can be present but have no disease. Additionally, some bacteria cause all manner of conditions. Strep, for example, can cause infections in every part of the body. The type of dataset you would need is highly dependent upon the questions you are trying to answer. There may be better ways to get at your answer if you can clarify the questions you are trying to ask.

Comment: If you have NLP tools with bacteria names  - you can parse eMedicine.com which will give you diagnoses and bacteria causing them.

Comment: @Praxiteles Thank you! to clarify, the question is if the bacteria is known to elicit any symptoms in humans, and if so, what are they.

Comment: A single bacteria can elicit hundreds even thousands of different symptoms - and the overlap is immense. (i.e. staph or strep could cause the various symptoms associated with infections of the ear, skin (anywhere on the body), respiratory system, throat, wounds, post-surgical (internally), eyes, sinuses and more. New discoveries occur every week. The number of symptoms is almost incalculable. Additionally, many infections are multi-microbial. Lastly, many bacteria are just colonizers.) What are you trying to solve with having symptoms? It is possible your project may need a different approach.

Comment: Here is another example to give context. The human body consists of 30 trillion human cells and 40 trillion bacteria..! If we got rid of every human cell there would still be a shadow of you from your bacteria. Bacteria live in your mouth. If you don't brush, they will form a biofilm. If you don't scrub it away, they will wall in and cause a periodontal infection. You may find a dozen different bacteria in the abscess they form. Are the bacteria infectious or not-infectious? Virtually all bacteria will eat you if they can. There is a constant balance and war.

Comment: Lastly, I will just add - are you certain what you are sequencing is the same as what is infecting? Bacteria often gain infectivity by acquiring DNA from other bacteria around them. The sequence you see for E.coli, for example, may be different than what causes infection. In some ways - what might be preferable is the symptoms from the patient and the genes of the bacteria that infected them. Then you can start to tease out what genes cause what patterns of infectivity.